# How to add percentage above the ggplot graph bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add the percentage above the bars from a data.frame?

How could I use two decimal places after the comma.

I tried to apply ggplot, but I couldn't get it wrong:

```
a <- c("até 50","50-150","150-500","500-2000")
b <- c(107,38,14,3)
pcent <- c(66.049383, 23.456790, 8.641975, 1.851852)

df <- data.frame(a,b,pcent)

ggplot(df, aes (x=reorder(a, -b), y=b, label=pcent)) +
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7") +
  labs(x = "Faixa de desmatamento (ha)", y="Quantidade de polígonos de desmatamento", title = "Distribuição dos polígonos de desmatamento") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pcent, label = scales::percent(pcent)), vjust = -0.2)+
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your y-axis is raw count and you want to plot percentage on top of bars which can be bit misleading. Anyway, you can do :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes (x=reorder(a, -b), y=b, label=pcent)) +
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7") +
  labs(x = "Faixa de desmatamento (ha)", 
       y="Quantidade de polígonos de desmatamento", 
       title = "Distribuição dos polígonos de desmatamento") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(pcent,2), '%')), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Or probably better to show percentages on y-axis.

```
ggplot(df, aes (x=reorder(a, -b), y=pcent, label=pcent)) +
  geom_col(fill="#70A2E7") +
  labs(x = "Faixa de desmatamento (ha)", 
       y="Quantidade de polígonos de desmatamento", 
       title = "Distribuição dos polígonos de desmatamento") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(pcent,2), '%')), vjust = -0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, '%'))
```

[image]

Comment: hello @Ronak Shah, I actually noticed that the Y axis is wrong on the graph, as it should not appear as a percentage.

I ran your code and got successful. That was exactly what I was needing. Thanks for your help!!!